# Does Rust libc crate inhibit the compilation of custom panic handler?

Tags: rust, libc, rust-cargo

So we are currently trying to compile some Rust code that we can then link to some C code. To do this we are using Bindgen to generate an FFI, and then we will use it to call some C functions from Rust.

However, we must first have the crate "libc" as a dependency in the Cargo.toml file of the project. The project we are currently working on demands that we use the crate wide !#[no_std] attribute, as we don't want the entire stdlib of Rust. We only need the core. The [libc crate](https://crates.io/crates/libc) says we can "request" it not be linked to the standard library by putting some options in the Cargo.toml file, namely:

```
[dependencies]
libc = { version = "0.2", default-features = false }
```

This is all fine and dandy, but when we try to compile we get the following error message.

```
Ubuntu:~/nautilus/src/rust/example# cargo build
   Compiling example v0.0.0 (/home/me/nautilus/src/rust/example)
error[E0152]: duplicate lang item found: `panic_impl`.
  --> src/lib.rs:33:1
   |
33 | / pub fn nk_rust_panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> !
34 | | {
35 | |    // should call nk_panic here...
36 | |    loop { }
37 | | } 
   | |_^
   |
   = note: first defined in crate `std`.

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0152`.
error: Could not compile `example`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

E0152 is the following

````
A lang item was redefined.

Erroneous code example:

```
#![feature(lang_items)]

#[lang = "arc"]
struct Foo; // error: duplicate lang item found: `arc`
```

Lang items are already implemented in the standard library. Unless you are
writing a free-standing application (e.g. a kernel), you do not need to provide
them yourself.

You can build a free-standing crate by adding `#![no_std]` to the crate
attributes:

```
#![no_std]
```
````

Our lib.rs file has #![no_std] already in it, but it appears that since libc would normally link against stdlib, that maybe Rust thinks that we cannot have a custom panic handler if we are using libc.

The problem relieves itself when we remove libc from the Cargo.toml file, and remove the `extern crate lib` from lib.rs.

lib.rs

```
// no stdlib
#![no_std]

// Give us this feature to override?
#![feature(start)]

#![feature(lang_items)]

// avoid buildins - we want it to use our library
#![no_builtins]

// The following cruft is here to handle Rust->OS dependencies
// currently only one:  Rust needs to know how to panic
use core::panic::PanicInfo;

extern crate libc;
#[panic_handler]
#[no_mangle]
pub fn nk_rust_panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> !
{
   // should call nk_panic here... (panic handler of OS)
   loop { }
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "example"  # this is for core-kernel
version = "0.0.0"


[lib]
crate-type = ["staticlib"]

[dependencies]
libc = { version = "0.2", default-features = false }

[build-dependencies]
bindgen = "0.42.2"

[profile.dev]
panic = "abort"    # no stack unwind on rust panic

[profile.release]
panic = "abort"    # no stuck unwind on rust panic
```

So, in sum, does using libc as a dependency make us unable to use our own custom panic handler? Are there any wonky compiler flags we can pass directly to rustc to eliminate this problem?

Compiler is 1.32.0-nightly 
Libc version is libc v0.2.44

Answer (score 1):

You are running into a bug in Cargo.

Features are a bit subtle. They can be enabled by any transitive dependency, which is expected behaviour. However, they can even be enabled by transitive *build* dependencies, which is a [bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/5730).