# How to troubleshoot why cargo/rustc links in rust standard library symbols even when no_std is used?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to create an embed-friendly executable (small footprint and without dependency on the Rust standard library) that uses a library (wasmi) that already has support for a `no_std` build. New to Rust, I am simply piecing together instructions, but the gist of it appears to be [follow the steps](https://os.phil-opp.com/freestanding-rust-binary/).

For the executable:

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use core::panic::PanicInfo;

/// This function is called on panic.
#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {}
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn _start(_argc: isize, _argv: *const *const u8) -> ! {
    interpret(_argc, _argv);
    loop {}
}
```

That is to:

- include `#![no_std]`
- define our entry (not `main` since we don't have a runtime that will call it)
- and define a panic handler since the Rust std lib is not included to define it for us.

My Cargo file to compile this looks like this:

```
[package]
 name = "driver"
 version = "0.1.0"
 edition = "2018"

[dependencies.wasmi]
 path = "../../github_dev/wasmi" 
 features = ["core"]
 default-features = false
 test=false
 bench=false

 [profile.release]
 panic = "abort"
 lto = true
 incremental=false
 debug=true
 opt-level = "z"
 test=false
 bench=false
```

and produces a very small binary that excludes any standard library symbols (using `nm` to check) and runs as expected.

The problem occurs when I actually try to call a function from the wasmi library. It is built with `no_std` via the `features=core` line. Doing an `nm` on the files in `release/deps/libwasmi-*.rlib` shows no standard library symbols. However when linking occurs with this command:

```
rustc --release --verbose -- -C link-arg=-nostartfiles
```

it leads to:

```
   Compiling driver v0.1.0 (/home/my_home/wasmi_embed/driver)
     Running rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name driver src/main.rs --color always --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C panic=abort -C lto -C link-arg=-nostartfiles -C metadata=957eda2e590447ba -C extra-filename=-957eda2e590447ba --out-dir /home/my_home/wasmi_embed/driver/target/release/deps -L dependency=/home/my_home/wasmi_embed/driver/target/release/deps --extern libc=/home/my_home/wasmi_embed/driver/target/release/deps/liblibc-f7fb773c7b059a14.rlib --extern wasmi=/home/my_home/wasmi_embed/driver/target/release/deps/libwasmi-534aef1926b4eb6c.rlib
```

and an error occurs:

```
error[E0152]: duplicate lang item found: panic_impl.
  --> src/main.rs:31:1
   |
31 | / pub extern fn panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
32 | |     loop {}
33 | | }
   | |_^
   |
   = note: first defined in crate `std`.
```

It seems Rust is trying to link in standard library support for at least panic handling, but I don't know why.

I would like help to understand why and to understand how to prevent it.

If I remove the `panic_impl` attribute then my executable compiles, but it includes a lot of  standard library symbols that I am trying to prevent.

The example symbols I see are:

```
my_home@my_puter:~/wasmi_embed/driver/target/release$ nm --demangle -A -a -B -s --line-number test_2018 2>/dev/null | grep std
driver:00000000000264c0 t rust_begin_unwind  /rustc/8e2063d02062ee9f088274690a97826333847e17//src/libstd/panicking.rs:311
driver:00000000000264a0 t rust_oom   /rustc/8e2063d02062ee9f088274690a97826333847e17//src/libstd/alloc.rs:203
driver:000000000001f490 t rust_panic /rustc/8e2063d02062ee9f088274690a97826333847e17//src/libstd/panicking.rs:524
driver:0000000000025aa0 t _$LT$std..panicking..continue_panic_fmt..PanicPayload$LT$$u27$a$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..panic..BoxMeUp$GT$::get::he4f810e299a2e0b4    /rustc/8e2063d02062ee9f088274690a97826333847e17//src/libstd/panicking.rs:372
driver:00000000000259a0 t _$LT$std..panicking..continue_panic_fmt..PanicPayload$LT$$u27$a$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..panic..BoxMeUp$GT$::box_me_up::hd8430725259668a8     /rustc/8e2063d02062ee9f088274690a97826333847e17//src/libstd/panicking.rs:367
driver:0000000000021520 t _$LT$std..sys_common..process..DefaultEnvKey$u20$as$u20$core..borrow..Borrow$LT$std..ffi..os_str..OsStr$GT$$GT$::borrow::hbacd0cd7d7fbf1c1/rustc/8e2063d02062ee9f088274690a97826333847e17//src/libstd/sys_common/process.rs:27
driver:0000000000021570 t _$LT$std..error..$LT$impl$u20$core..convert..From$LT$alloc..string..String$GT$$u20$for$u20$alloc..boxed..Box$LT$$LP$dyn$u20$std..error..Err
... plus more
```

The above symbols are not found in any of the rlib files under the `dep` directory including libwasmi, nor are they found in the driver executable when not calling libwasmi code.

I've read [a similar issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/5978) (hence my `test=false` and `bench=false` in the Cargo.toml) but that did not help. I've tried to build with just `rustc` with varying commands (excluding Cargo) but the error is the same. I've tried to compile wasmi as a static library (ar) and link it in, but being new to Rust I was spending a lot of time trying to link it in and it just wasn't happening.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I believe your question may be answered by the answers of [Does Rust libc crate inhibit the compilation of custom panic handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545506/does-rust-libc-crate-inhibit-the-compilation-of-custom-panic-handler). If you disagree, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster, Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I did happen to see that post and had forgotten about it. Since there was only one answer (with one vote) and no solution, I didn't know what to make of it. Not shown in my code above was an inclusion `extern crate libc` but when I remove this code it does not prevent the error. The one answer though points to a cargo bug where use_std is included unexpectedly. I did not quite follow all the thread and I do not use xcargo but looking at verbose output of my build I do not see use_std being included. Still, I will look deeper into this bug to confirm.

Comment: @Shepmaster .. I just noticed the part about please edit or have this marked as already answered. I think it is impossible to call this question already having been answered by the one pointed to considering has no accepted solution. There is only one response with one up vote and no comments from the questioner. The proposed answer points to a bug on github that I do see some parallels but certainly can't say it is a duplicate. I'd much rather give people time to view this issue and comment and help rather than dismissing as a duplicate to a post that has almost no activity and no solution.

Comment: Note that a question does not have to hold an accepted answer to be considered useful (only the asker can do that, and they might forget/choose not to do it for arbitrary reasons). The answer there suggests that any build dependency could be pushing a panic handler. But considering that I don't see any other dependencies in your example other than `wasmi`, there _could_ be something else at play that makes it worth investigating further.

Comment: Thanks @E_net4 .. I agree with @shipmaster there are parallels and that each of our questions could be prompted by the same underlying issue. I don't though see output in the `--verbose` build that makes it clear something is causing std lib to be used. I really want suggestions to help explain how to figure out what crate or code is causing std code to be brought in. There is a command `cargo metadata` that I can run and see a bunch of dependencies. In particular scopeguard appears to have a use_std feature, but when I do an nm on that rlib I can't see any unwind or other std lib functions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved this after seeking some help in the rust forums. [enter link description here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/solved-how-to-troubleshoot-why-and-prevent-cargo-rustc-links-in-crate-std-when-no-std-is-specified/25233). Specifically, was not able to determine what was responsible for rust std lib being linked into my executable ... was it an issue with a crate or an issue with cargo or an issue with rustc or an issue with the linker. I did not know where the problem was born, but based on similar bugs filed I figured that somehow a crate was being compiled to bring in std lib unexpected. Turns out bug [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545506/does-rust-libc-crate-inhibit-the-compilation-of-custom-panic-handler) was not related even though the error message was the same. I did not have an issue with unexpected propagations form different type of dependencies (dev-dependencies and build-dependencies). I tried all these techniques to pinpoint what was bringing in std lib:

1. I tried using cargo tree to list dependencies to list all the crate
   dependencies:

   wasmi v0.4.3 (/home/jlb6740/github_dev/wasmi)
   ├── byteorder v1.3.1 (/home/jlb6740/github_dev/byteorder)
   ├── hashbrown v0.1.8 (/home/jlb6740/github_dev/hashbrown)
   │   ├── byteorder v1.3.1 (/home/jlb6740/github_dev/byteorder) (*)

   │   └── scopeguard v0.3.3 (/home/jlb6740/github_dev/scopeguard)

   ├── libm v0.1.2

   ├── memory_units v0.3.0

   └── parity-wasm v0.31.0 (/home/jlb6740/github_dev/parity-wasm)

       └── byteorder v1.3.1 (/home/jlb6740/github_dev/byteorder) (*)
2. I tried using cargo rustc --verbose … but at this time verbose does
   not indicate anything was using default features which may include
   using std
3. I tried using cargo metadata … this generated a long list of
   dependencies that was hard to parse, but I did see some instances
   where scopeguard and byteorder had default features requiring std
   support. I downloaded all of these crates and just hardcoded
   attributes so that the crates would only build with no_std support.
4. I tried looking at the deps/ output and did an nm on all of the
   rlibs to see if any of the libraries used symbols found in std. I
   could not find that that was the case. I thought rlibs were like
   static libraries and that anything they used would be included in
   the rlib but apparently not.
5. I looked at cargo rustc -- -C --print-link-args to check out linker
   flags but I could not find anything obvious telling me it was
   bringing in std lib.

None of these things helped me to pinpoint what was introducing std lib. Ultimately the suggestion at the rust forums was to use cargo check for a target that does not allow std lib at all. Those with a `*` listed here: [enter link description here](https://forge.rust-lang.org/platform-support.html#tier-3) have only core support. I tried that, running with `--target=thumbv7m-none-eabi` and saw:

error[E0463]: can’t find crate for alloc
–> /home/jlb6740/github_dev/hashbrown/src/lib.rs:44:1
|
44 | extern crate std as alloc;
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can’t find crate

Turns out it was hashbrown which was a dependency of a dependency of my executable. It built no_std by default but had an extern std linked under a different name and which was guarded by a feature called “nightly”. The guard was disabled in my efforts to not build anything but no_std. Nothing I’d tried alerted me to the crate which was responsible until this. Seems there should be a better way to get a more comprehensive list of crate dependencies than what cargo tree provided, but changing the wasmi cargo to make sure the nightly feature was set solved my issue.